# Failed to set remote offer sdp: Failed to create channels

Tags: android, webrtc

The error happens on these two lines:

`mPeerConnectionClient.setRemoteDescription(new SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.OFFER, Sdp()));`

`mPeerConnectionClient.createAnswer();`

In which conditions the error can occur?

**Update:**

This seems to the solution but not yet tested: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!starred/discuss-webrtc/omiojGomEI4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved from comment on this questions:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!starred/discuss-webrtc/omiojGomEI4